# Uploading Videos and Image

Tags: android, image, video, snapchat

Does anyone have any idea about what does snapchat uses to upload videos and images to the server? I mean does it compress the images and video? if anyone has any idea, please help me.

Comment: because its uploading the videos and images to server very fast

Answer (score 0):

I think your question re snapchat specifically is not going to get you a response, or at not least one you want (unless @Ronak really does have the code and is going to share it!!).

Also, this is a core part of SnapChats business so they have a lot more resource to throw at the solution and hence may be able to implement something that is beyond the budget or resources of others.

Assuming what you really want is the ability to compress images on Android so you can upload them more quickly, then you can either build your own solution, for example using ffmpeg on Android (possibly through a wrapper like: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) or, probably a better approach, use a well supported open source solution or library such as:

- https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor